# Typescript React useEffect Deps issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React with TypeScript and want to make use of the `useEffect` hook.

I would like to do something like this

1. Create 1st `useEffect` to listen to some rxJs observable which will set one particular property of the internal state for my component (this bit is working)
2. I would then like to listen to the particular property of my components internal state changing, and when it changes would like to do something in a 2nd `useEffect` (this will likely call a redux dispatch action)

This is the initial state

```
const initialState = {
    isopen: false,
    selectedNodeText : ''
}
```

This part works

```
const Home: React.FunctionComponent<HomeProps> = (props) => {

    const [currentState, setState] = useState(initialState);

    useEffect(() => {

        const sub = props.eventMessager.observe()
        .pipe(
            filter((event: IMessage) => event instanceof ShowInfoInSidePanel),
            map((event: IMessage) => event as ShowInfoInSidePanel)
        )
        .subscribe(x => {
            setState({ ...currentState, isopen: true, selectedNodeText: x.itemClicked });
        });


        return () => {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }, []); 
}
```

But I would the like to add a 2nd `useEffect` where i pass in the particular property of the state to listen to, so this is what I have

```
useEffect(() => {
   //TODO : make a async redux thunk call to get the data
}, [currentState.selectedNodeText]);
```

But I am getting this error

[image]

But all the examples of using `useEffect` with TypeScript just do what I am doing. What do I need to do to convert my `string[]` into a `ReadOnlyArray<any>` to keep `useEffect` happy?

Comment: why do you want things to trigger on just selectedNodeText update? the way you have written you always set the "whole" state, so you can just listen to currentState change

Comment: Since `ReadonlyArray` is just a Typescript type, you could cast your array to it. Like `[currentState.selectedNodeText] as ReadonlyArray<string>`.

Comment: @PompolutZ that shows the same problem

Comment: @Alexander Cerutti I then get this error 'cannot convert string[] to ReadOnlyArray<string>'

Comment: The conversion should work. The two types are compatible. (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKANgpgLgBAzgLnlATgSwHYHMDaBdGAXhhwCIBDUgGhlICNS8BuUSWcpAJQnIBMB7DGACeAQRQpywgDzkMwgHwwAPjACuGXhABmmCLyLwWIUEA) in typescript playground). If you get such error it seems like an issue with your project configuration, or editor plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it might be a dummy example, but the idea here is that we get console.log output only when is currentState.selectedNodeText is changing but not when other part of the state is changing:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface IState {
  isopen: boolean;
  selectedNodeText: string;
}

const initialState: IState = {
  isopen: false,
  selectedNodeText: ""
};

interface CardProps {
  Title: string;
  Image: string;
  Body: string;
}

export const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ Title }) => {
  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = React.useState<IState>(initialState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Changed");
  }, [currentState.selectedNodeText]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCurrentState({
      ...currentState,
      isopen: true,
      selectedNodeText: `${Math.random()}`
    });
  };

  const handleChangeIsOpen = () => {
    setCurrentState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      isopen: !prev.isopen
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="title">{Title}</div>
      <div className="body">{`IsOpen ${currentState.isopen} with text ${
        currentState.selectedNodeText
      }`}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change Selected Node Text</button>
      <button onClick={handleChangeIsOpen}>Change isOpen</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card Title="CardTitle" Image="Image" Body="Body" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-sea-26qcy

Comment: ok so you are doing exactly the same as I was trying to do and I can see in your sandbox you dont get typescript complaining at you.

I have checked your tsconfig against mine and they look the same. But for me it complains in typescript as I show above.  What else could be casing this. I am using Resharper too, so perhaps that is using an incorrect TypeScript compatibility mode or something. Got any ideas what else could be causing me errors but not you.....If I take you exact example and paste it into new tsx file, it complains as I show in my original screenshot.

Comment: Does it complains in your sandbox or in your "real" environment?

Comment: I have updated example with setting current state to explicit interface

Comment: this is all just local right now. So I disabled Resharper, and although it still complains, it was able to run ok. So there is something fishy going on here with resharper I think. I am going to mark your answer as accepted answer, as this clearly seems to be something wrong with Resharper and Typescript checking. Thanks for the help

Comment: But have you tried to explicitly set type of the current state, according to updated sandbox? I don't use Typescript myself, but if I use, I want to benefit from type explicity, at least when it cannot deduce type implicitly?

Comment: yeah i tried that didn't seem to get rid of original error. If I turn off Resharper (code analysis tool for .NET) all is ok

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency problem in your effect, not sure if typescript would notice but eslint with react-hooks will tell you about it. You could try to pass a callback to state setter so currentState is not a dependency.

The props. eventMessager will still be a dependency so make sure you don't change reference of this passed prop when parent re renders because if it does it'll unsubscribe and subscribe every time.

```
const Home: React.FunctionComponent<HomeProps> = (props) => {

  const [currentState, setState] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
      const sub = props.eventMessager.observe()
      .pipe(
          filter((event: IMessage) => event instanceof ShowInfoInSidePanel),
          map((event: IMessage) => event as ShowInfoInSidePanel)
      )
      .subscribe(x => {
          //pass callback to setState to prevent currentState
          //  being a dependency
          setState(
            (currentState)=>({ 
              ...currentState,
              isopen: true,
              selectedNodeText: x.itemClicked
            })
          );
      });

      return () => {
          sub.unsubscribe();
      }
  }, [props.eventMessager]); //add props.eventMessager as dependency
}
```

The other error you get is probably because you pass in a dependency that you are not using, try the following:

```
useEffect(
  () => console.log(currentState.selectedNodeText),//using the dependency
  [currentState.selectedNodeText]
);
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd part of your answer, still get the error.

Comment: @sacha What if you do: `const selectedNodeText= currentState.selectedNodeText; useEffect(
  () => console.log(selectedNodeText),
  [selectedNodeText]
);`

Comment: same deal. Listen dont worry, think its a resharper issue. Code works when I run it without Resharper. Seems to be issue with that. Though my understanding was that you would pass in the dependencies. So if I copy the value to this const, how does the dependency change tracking work then?

Comment: @sacha There is a problem with your linter because the effect that you say is just fine is actually missing dependencies and no dev tools you are using are telling you about it. Tracking of the dependency doesn't change but maybe your devtool that complains about it will recognise it better.

Comment: @sacha In my answer I added the dependency and set the state with a callback for the first effect and use the dependency in the second. Although that doesn't seem to be your problem. Maybe you can try it with vscode and the eslint plugin set up with [exhaustive deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)

Comment: ok so I tried in VSCode rather than full VS + R#, and seems ok. So it is as  I/we/you suspected its an issue with R#.......Again thanks for all the help